# Unable to see menu bar present on top of Answer body

Tags: discussion, bug

I am unable to see Menu bar present on top of Body.. Is it bug or I am the only one who is unable to see this menu bar

**Browser :**

**Chrome version: 73.0.3683.103**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

**Internet Explorer**

[image]

> Only for stackoverflow.com

Comment: [WFM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCJPn.jpg) on Firefox Android Desktop. It's helpful to mention your browser version, if you have many tabs open or programs running, and mention that you've closed and reopened your browser and the problem persists; even after disabling plugins and user scripts, etc.

Comment: I updated my question. I tried with refreshing page also tried with Hard refresh

Comment: I face the same issue. Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I don't see it on Stack Overflow either. If that's the only site you see it on you'll get more exposure and less likelihood of your question being closed if you ask on SO's Meta instead of the main Meta for all sites (when it's only applicable to one site, and not this one).

Comment: @Rob I am getting the same issue with just SO. Meta and other Stack Exchange sites work fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is off topic here. To report site specific bugs, please do it on that site meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was due to refactoring in JS and Typescript files.
You can find [Q&A thread here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384453/6299857)

I guess, changes has been rolled back, Now I am able to see  Menu bar.

[image]